# kendo ui data-show not work

Tags: html, kendo-ui

I'm work with kendo ui at html5, and I need some action happen each time the page is displayed.
Just for that is the "data-show" option, but it not work.
The function fire only at the first time and no more.

```
<div id="div1" data-role="view" data-show="alert(999)">
    // The content of the div
</div>
```

The alert fire only one time.
Any Idea?
Thanks.

Comment: can you explain what you need in more detail? what do you mean by "each time the page is displayed"? do you mean when someone goes to look at another app and comes back to the browser? do you mean page refresh? do you mean switching tabs in the browser? there's not enough info in this question to provide a good answer

Comment: If the user go to the next page, and then returning to previous page, the page is showing again but the function is not fire.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a JavaScript function which will handle the show event:

```
<div id="div1" data-role="view" data-show="div1Show">
</div>

<script>
function div1Show() {
  alert(999);
}
</script>
```

Here is a short demo demonstrating the same: http://jsbin.com/abaveh/1/edit

Comment: I tried that and it did not work.
In the example I wrote with the alert to be more than just understanding the question.

Comment: Works as expected when I test it. Here is a proof: http://screencast.com/t/UZUgSr7pZdBS